# Saving canvas content as image on Parse platform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, parse-platform

I am trying to save the content of an html canvas as an image on the Parse.com platform. I have managed to save text as well as photos, but have run into a roadblock when trying to save the canvas. I send the canvas toDataURL()

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

then try to set that value for the base64

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", {base64:dataURL});
```

but clearly I'm missing something because it does not save an image. 
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzudh1on/) of my project. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured this out. It is necessary to first remove the beginning `data:image/jpeg;base64` using `dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");`.